# How can run multiple celery tasks in parallel?

Tags: python, django, celery, worker

I have a two tasks.

```
@app.task
def run1():
    while True:
        print('run1')
        time.sleep(5)
    return


@app.task
def run2():
    while True:
        print('run2')
        time.sleep(2)
    return
```

How can I run these two tasks at the same time from the same console, from one command (preferably with a different number of `workers`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`group`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives):

> The group primitive is a signature that takes a list of tasks that should be applied in parallel.

Example from django shell:

```
>>> from celery import group
>>> from myapp.tasks import run1, run2
>>>
>>> run_group = group(run1.s(), run2.s())
>>> run_group()
<GroupResult: 06b3e88b-6c10-4ba5-bb32-5005c82eedfe [cc734fbd-3531-45d1-8575-64f4eff35523, 
1075e822-a6e2-4c34-8038-369613ff687d]>
```

For more complex usage, see the docs on [group](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups).